# What are typical use cases of scrextend?

Tags: koma-script

I see this package often loaded but find quick description of the relevance of the package hard to come by.

> makes some features of the KOMA-Script classes available for other classes

I had never heard of KOMA-script before, it is not mentioned in any of the three books I have on LaTeX. But I see there is also a package with the name `koma-script`.

I'm looking for some typical issues koma-script/scrextend use cases. In other words, what likely to break if I remove it?

Comment: you can find the commands it defines in the documentation (open it with `texdoc scrguide`). And it depends on your document what will break if you remove it. Try it out.

Comment: If you want the documentation in English, use `texdoc scrguien` instead.

Comment: I guess I am looking for something like "Top 3 things that `scrextend` can do". If I do either `texdoc scrguien` or `texdoc scrguide` I get in both cases."No viewer associated with file type."

Comment: You can find the documenation also on CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrextend
See chapter 10 »Using Basic Features of the KOMA -Script Classes in Other
Classes with the scrextend Package«.